# NodeJS returning incomplete response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have a GETTER NodeJS API (NodeJS and MongoDB).

```
    //! Add Json Support: Tested
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
    app.get('/api/settings/otherusers/get/:userid', function(req , res){
        //! Extract Main User Details Details*/
        var user = req.params.userid;
        console.log("[User-PErmission-Query-Request][TimeStamp:" + new Date().toISOString() + "]" + user);
        //! Insert the registration record in DataBase*/
        requests.getpermission(res, user , function (found) {
            if(found != null)
            {
                res.json(found);    
                res.end();                    
            }
        });            
});
```

Since it is supposed to fetch results from MongoDB, I designed a function that internally calls another function that actually returns the results in CALLBACK exported by calling function.

My Calling Function:

```
//! Allowing User to Query all dependent registered user and their permissions
exports.getpermission = function(res, user, callback){   
        var result = {};
        result.other_user = [];    
        result.other_user_permissions = [];   
        RetrieveUserDetails(user, 
        function(err, user, current, totaluser){
          if(!err)
          {
            result.other_user.push(user);
          }
          else
          {
            //! End Processing
            callback({
                "user": 
                  {
                    "responseCode":"404",
                    "userId": user, 
                    "messasge": "No Record Found" 
                  }
              }  
            ); 
          }
        }, 
        function(err, permit, current, totalpermit){
          if(!err)
          {
            result.other_user_permissions.push(permit);
          }
          else
          {
            //! End Processing
            callback({
                "user": 
                  {
                    "responseCode":"404",
                    "userId": user, 
                    "messasge": "No Record Found" 
                  }
              }  
            ); 
          }
        },
        function(status)
        {
          if(true == status)
          {
            //! JSON Response
            var json_response = {};
            json_response.responseCode = 200; //! Okay Response
            var otherusers = []
            json_response.otherusers = otherusers;    //! Other users
            //! Logging all users
            for (var i = 0; i < result.other_user.length; i++){
              var otheruser = {
                "otheruserId": result.other_user[i].other_user_id,
                "otheruserName": result.other_user[i].other_name,
                "permissions": []                
              };
              //! Logging all permissions
              for (var j = 0; j < result.other_user_permissions.length; j++){
                if(result.other_user[i].other_user_id == result.other_user_permissions[j].other_user_id)
                {
                  otheruser.permissions.push({"alert_type": result.other_user_permissions[j].alert_type,
                    "value": result.other_user_permissions[j].value
                  });
                }
              }
              json_response.otherusers.push(otheruser);
            }
            res.json(json_response);
            res.end();
            //callback(JSON.stringify(json_response, null, 2));                         
            //console.log("##########################################");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json_response, null, 2));
            //! End Processing
          }
          else
          {
            //! End Processing
            callback({
                "user": 
                  {
                    "responseCode":"404",
                    "userId": user, 
                    "messasge": "No record found" 
                  }
              }  
            );                                     
          }
        });        
}
```

My Called Function:

```
function RetrieveUserDetails(user, callbackuser, callbackpermit, callbackend)
{
        var i = 0;                  /*Users*/
        var j = 0;                  /*Permissions*/
        var totalusers = 0;         /*total number of users*/
        var totalpermissions = 0;   /*total number of permisions*/
        //! Check if the user already exists in Database*/
        msil_users.find({user_id: user}, function(err,users){
        //! A given user with same phone number exists*/
        if((users.length != 0) && (!err))
        {
             console.log("\n[User-Found]: "+ "UserName: "+ users[0].f_name + " User-ID: "+ users[0].user_id);
             //! Check for all registered users for a given primary user
             msil_other_users.find({parent_user_id: user}).exec(function(err,users){
             totalusers = users.length;
             //! Update other_user array
             for(i = 0; i< users.length; i++)
             {
                //Send User Information
                callbackuser(null, users[i], i, users.length);
                //! Check for all registered users for a given primary user
                msil_other_users_permit.find({other_user_id: users[i].other_user_id}).exec(function(err,permission){
                   totalpermissions = permission.length;
                   //! Update other_user array
                   for(j = 0; j < permission.length; j++)
                   {
                      callbackpermit(null, permission[j] , j, permission.length);                     
                      //! End Criteria
                      if((i >= (totalusers-1)) && (j >= (totalpermissions-1)))
                      {
                        console.log("CurrentUser- "+ i + " CurrentPermission-"+ j + " TotalUser-"+ totalusers + " TotalPermissions-"+ totalpermissions);                        
                        return callbackend(true);
                      }
                   }
                });
             }             
          });
        }
        else
        {
          callbackuser("No User Exists", null);
          callbackpermit("No Permission Exists", null);
          return callbackend(false);
        }
    });  
}
```

I am getting two times output in console (first one is wrong and second one is right). I am unable to figure out why I am getting two outputs.

```
[User-PErmission-Query-Request][TimeStamp:2016-05-09T21:06:27.899Z]Abhishek98304
75278

[User-Found]: UserName: Abhishek User-ID: Abhishek
CurrentUser- 3 CurrentPermission-1 TotalUser-3 TotalPermissions-2
{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "otherusers": [
    {
      "otheruserId": "BharatiDhar",
      "otheruserName": "BharatiDhar",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "alert_type": "intrusion_alert",
          "value": "ON"
        },
        {
          "alert_type": "eCall",
          "value": "ON"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "otheruserId": "PrithaMoulik",
      "otheruserName": "PrithaMoulik",
      "permissions": []
    },
    {
      "otheruserId": "FarhatRahaman",
      "otheruserName": "FarhatRahaman",
      "permissions": []
    }
  ]
}
##########################################
GET /api/settings/otherusers/get/Abhishek 200 33ms - 392b
CurrentUser- 3 CurrentPermission-1 TotalUser-3 TotalPermissions-2
{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "otherusers": [
    {
      "otheruserId": "BharatiDhar",
      "otheruserName": "BharatiDhar",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "alert_type": "intrusion_alert",
          "value": "ON"
        },
        {
          "alert_type": "eCall",
          "value": "ON"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "otheruserId": "PrithaMoulik",
      "otheruserName": "PrithaMoulik",
      "permissions": []
    },
    {
      "otheruserId": "FarhatRahaman",
      "otheruserName": "FarhatRahaman",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "alert_type": "eCall",
          "value": "ON"
        },
        {
          "alert_type": "intrusion_alert",
          "value": "ON"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
##########################################
```

Please help, I am unable to solve this problem. I come from a C++ background and not that familiar with NodeJS.